# Live wallpaper in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, desktop-background

Is there any recent method to get live wallpapers in Ubuntu? I am talking about wallpaper styling that we have in android phones and that should be reactivity to some hover and mouse-clicks?

Thanks

Comment: Try komorebi [komorebi Github Repo](https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi). You can follow this [guide](https://itsfoss.com/live-wallpaper-ubuntu-komorebi/)

Comment: Does this have reactivity to some hover and mouse-clicks? Thank you. :)

Comment: Not really live wallpaper but Cairo-Dock (`sudo apt-get install cairo-dock) can be installed from repositories to give you reactivity to hover/mouse clicks and run system commands, or xdotool to replicate keyboard shortcuts etc. I use it on a couple of touchscreen PCs (themed to fit the wallpaper and so it does not look like a dock) to to home automation tasks. It's an old/dead project and a bit clunky to configure but it is very configurable. Maybe in combination with the live wallpaper suggested above you might be able to do what you want.

Comment: Also conky is very good and flexible for providing a live-wallpaper look. Although I do not know if you can do any interactive / clickable / reactive things with it.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: Komorebi has not been maintained since 2018, and you may have issues with it.

I would highly recommend [Komorebi](https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi/releases).

It's more dynamic and cross platform.

Comment: unfortunaly this repo is o longer being maintained

Comment: in addition, komorebi does not run on wayland

Comment: I would highly recommend that you do NOT use Komorebi. Myself and many others spent hours trying to get back desktop icons and desktop right-click functionality after trying it.

Comment: @DaveL. you are right it has been a long time since I used this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
in terminal type: xwininfo -name Desktop

xwininfo: Window id: 0x1400013 "Desktop"

(If -name Desktop is not working for you, then execute xwininfo without
options and just click on the desktop.)

copy only id
(my id is the same after reboots - so you can put it in script or autostart)

use id in mpv commandline options
mpv --no-osc --no-osd-bar --quiet --screen=0 --wid=0x1400013 --loop yourfile.*

Works for me using Xubuntu (xfce)